# Cisco 9300 Stacking Issue -- Link OK Yes, Link Active No

Tags: cisco-catalyst, stacking, stackwise

hopefully another pair of eyes can help me out with this. We have 4 Cisco 9300-24Ts data-stacked with all cables detected by the switches themselves. Switch order and priority looks good, however we are getting "Half bandwidth". I believe it is due to the last stacking cable in the ring not moving to "Link Active".
[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried enabling the stack port with this command on each switch

**switch 1 stack port 2 enable**

**switch 4 stack port 1 enable**

Comment: Never use images for test in your post. Simply copy the text and past it into the question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). You could then alter the sensitive information, but a MAC address on a different network is not sensitive information because a MAC address is only relevant or seen on the local network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a bad cable, or it's not plugged in all the way.  The ports are showing DOWN.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I thought we had reseated, but I guess not. Had tech reseat all is good.  Very werid that both switches detected the cable. Thanks!